# how to update a single row in my acumatica database

Tags: c#, acumatica

Hello I'm new and I am creating a customization project on my persist on Acumatica so I added a new field

```
public class UsersExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.SM.Users>
    {
        #region UsrMomentTrackID
        [PXDBString]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Moment Track ID")]

        public virtual string UsrMomentTrackID { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrMomentTrackID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrMomentTrackID> { }
        #endregion
```

I want to update loop on all field on the users database here is my current code but it returns me an error that its too long

```
  PXUpdate<Set<UsersExt.usrMomentTrackID, Add<UsersExt.usrMomentTrackID, Current<UsersExt.usrMomentTrackID>>>, Users,
                    Where<Users.pKID, Like<Users.pKID>>>.Update(Base, MomentTrackID, useritems.PKID);
```

Can you guide me on what I'm doing wrong or do we have a more effective way of updating a field on Acumatica database?

Comment: Cannot help without the error.

Comment: The approach doesn't seem right at all, I think we can answer without the error message.

Comment: Are you trying to populate all existing records within the system? Or are you trying to update the field on the specific action of a page ( such as updating your custom field when a field changes ).

Comment: Question title says single row and the code provided also implies single record because it uses pKID to select the record. The 'update loop on all fields' part is confusing.

Comment: On second thought (after thorough examination), the attempt here might be to use PXDatabase.Update in the context of the Persist method override. That would be a valid use case, although discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PXSelect` method to get the record.

With the `PXCache` object you can update and persist the record.

```
// 1. Select Users record
Guid? pKID = useritems.PKID;
Users user = PXSelect<Users, Where<Users.pKID, Equal<Required<Users.pKID>>>>.Select(Base, pKID);

if (user != null)
{
    // 2. Select Users DAC extension
    UsersExt userExt = user.GetExtension(user);

    if (userExt != null)
    {
        // 3. Set field value
        userExt.UsrMomentTrackID = MomentTrackID;

        // 4. Update record
        PXCache cache = Base.Caches[typeof(Users)];
        cache.Update(user);

        // 5. Persist record
        cache.Persist(user, PXDBOperation.Update);
    }
}
```

There's two context in which you can't use that method. Those are the `RowPersisted` event or the `Persist` method override. If you were to use the normal method to persist the record in those events it would call the same events again producing an infinite loop.

To workaround those issues you can use the `PXDatabase` class to persist directly to database. Note that this persisting method doesn't run DAC and Graph validations so it should be avoided as much as possible, it is not best practice to use that method but it can be helpful sometimes.

```
PXDatabase.Update<Users>(new PXDataFieldAssign<UsersExt.usrMomentTrackID>(MomentTrackID),
                         new PXDataFieldRestrict<Users.pKID>(useritems.PKID));
```

In general best practice is to add the custom field on screen, initialize it's value if necessary and let the end user persist the change by pressing the save button.